# 500 Internal Server Error, but works fine on localhost - $mysqli = new mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, internal-server-error

I'm trying to download a csv file getting contents from database, but I want to get it's name from the database as well from a single table (filename) with a single field (name).

Here's my code:

```
// Connecting to Database

$mysqli = new mysqli('servername.ipagemysql.com', 'username', 'pass', 'reportconverter');
$filename = array_values(mysqli_fetch_array($mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM filename")))[0]; 

//Downloading the file

header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);

echo $output;

exit;
```

I get the following error:

*Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.*

The servername, username, password and DB name are all accurate, because they are working on other pages. The code also works on local host. But if I put server login details in the localhost file, I get this error:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Any ideas? Or shall I ask my hosting service for help?

Comment: `But if I put server login details in the localhost file, I get this error` That means your mysql host permissions don't allow remote mysql connection. Setting those permissions correctly will resolve that

Comment: A `500` error means the *webserver* doesn't have the permissions to do whatever it's trying to do, similar to `403`.

Comment: If your server refused the connection, it means that there is a problem with mysql services running on the server, its not your fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I fixed the problem. It was the [0] causing the issue, because the php version on my server doesn't support that statement, so I had to change it like this:

```
$filename = array_values(mysqli_fetch_array($mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM filename"))); 
$filename = $filename[0];
```